# Problems with XCode errors/warnings / How to nuke XCode caches

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, xcode5.1

I've gotten to Chapter 23 in the 4th edition of the BNR iOS 7 book. I'm getting warnings on the solution code that don't go away. I suspect I need to nuke caches, but I don't know where or what to nuke. Any assistance cleaning up XCode 5.1 would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're going to need more specifics, like what the warnings are.

Comment: Doesn't `Product`/`Clean` do the trick?

Comment: I'm trying to load code from BNR Solution sets and I'm getting "Format String Issue" and "Value Conversion Issue" warnings. This is supposed to be "clean" code, error/warning free and it has been up to this point.

I encountered issues w/ my iOS Simulator earlier today that had to do w/ cache issues. I suspect I've got some cache issues here, too. Before I go nuking anything, I was hoping for some guidance on what to nuke.

Comment: Product/Clean did the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

- The usual way to do this is **Product**->**Clean**.
- A slightly more extreme version is to hold down the Option key while going to the **Product** menu. **Clean** becomes **Clean Build Folder**.
- The nuclear option is to delete the compiler temporaries yourself. The compiler temporaries are in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. Quit Xcode, then trash that entire directory. This also deletes the compiled apps, but you can just recompile them. It does *not* delete your archives.

That said, your warnings and errors are probably real.

Comment: Yeah, this is what you do if Clean doesn't quite hack it.  But it effectively deletes all your compiled apps, so something of a last resort.

Comment: It does at that, though if you're using them you've likely copied them out. I'll add a note to this effect, though.